# Relations Laravel 4 with 3 tables using Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to make a relation with 3 table using ORM but cant. My tables

User table

```
id | userame | name |
 1    Ellie    Elen
 2    Pol      Paul
```

record table

```
id | user_id| item_id| hour|
 1    2         1       3
 2    2         2       5
```

Item table table

```
id |  title 
 1    item 1  
 2    item 2
```

I am using this logic but not work properly

```
class User Extends Eloquent {

  public function record()
   {
    return $this->hasMany('VolunteerRecord');
   }

}


class VolunteerRecord Extends Eloquent {

    function item() {
        return $this->hasMany('VolunteerItem');
    }

}
```

I cant understand how to do it?

Comment: What is not working properly? What is your desired output? What are you getting currently? If there is an error, then could you update your question with the stack trace?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you want a Many-To-Many relationship between `Users` and `Items` but you also want to track hours on the pivot table. So first, you'll define the many-to-many relationships using [`belongsToMany()`](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#many-to-many), and you'll tell Laravel that you have extra data on your pivot table with the [`withPivot()`](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#working-with-pivot-tables) function. Your classes will look like this:

```php
class User extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'users';

    public function items() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Item', 'records')->withPivot('hour');
    }
}

class Item extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'items';

    public function users() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'records')->withPivot('hour');
    }
}
```

Then, to access the `hour` field you would do this:

```php
$user = User::first(); // First User
$item = $user->items()->first(); // User's first Item
$hour = $item->pivot->hour; // The 'hour' on the User-Item relationship
```

Also, your current column naming scheme is correct for Laravel so don't feel like you need to change it. If you change your column names, then you'll need to define them in the `belongsToMany()` method like this:

```php
$this->belongsToMany('ModelName', 'pivot_table', 'foreign_key', 'other_key');

// For example, in Items::users() you would have this:
$this->belongsToMany('User', 'records', 'users_id', 'items_id');
```

Finally, I'm assuming that your tables are named `users`, `items`, and `records`. If they are not, then just replace all instances of `users`, `items`, and `records` with your actual table names.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your table names, I'd suggest the following, first of all, change your record table as follows:

```
id | users_id| items_id| hour|
 1    2         1       3
 2    2         2       5
```

And these are the classes for your models:

```
class Users extends Eloquent
{
    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    public function records()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Records');
    }
}


class Records extends Eloquent
{
    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'records';

    public function record()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Users');
    }

    public function item()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Items');
    }
}

class Items extends Eloquent
{
    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'items';

    public function records()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Records');
    }
}
```

These contain the relations for your models.
If you were to select a few records, for each record you can get the user and the item. If you were to select an item, and all records for that item. You can also get the user for each record.

Comment: This won't work because `hasOne()` expects columns to have standard column names if you don't explicitly pass them into the function. You tell him to change his column names to non-standard names though.

Answer (score 0):

In User Model

```
public function images()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Item')->withPivot('hour');
}
```

In user controller

```
public function view($username)
{
    $user = User::where('name',$username)->firstOrFail();
    return View::make('view')->with('user',$user);
}
```

In view

```
    @foreach ($users->items as $item)
        name: {{$image->title}}<br>

        hour: {{$image->pivot->hour}}<br>
    @endforeach
```